# Shipping in magento 1.9

Tags: shipping

I have configured the method of calculation for each region is finished, but also one that, if the bill over $ 500, I will free shipping, which I do not know the configuration of items, you do know the show I think this is my website, no test you try this out http://dreamsfashion.com.vn, please help me,

please, I thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

System > Configuration > Sales > Shipping Methods

Then find section Free Shipping, enable it and set Minimum Order Amount to 500.

Comment: but it does show field select box " free shipping"  in the checkout page, it does not have the same hidden rates table

Comment: sorry I don't understand what do you mean